# MeshLab is not responding after "Remeshing, simplification and reconstruction – Surface reconstruction: Screened poisson"

Tags: meshlab

Whenever I convert a point cloud to a 3d drawing with lines my laptops crashes. I tried on a Macbook Pro 2021 16” with a M1 PRO and on a Macbook pro 13” Mid 2012.

My procedure/sequence is as follows:

Filerts – Normals, Curvatures and orientation – Compute normal for point sets (Neighbor number 5) or (Neighbor number 10)

Remeshing, simplification and reconstruction – Surface reconstruction: Screened poisson (Reconstruction depth 14)

***Crash appears, “MeshLab is not responding”***

Texture – parametrization: trival per triangle

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
// 2,5 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
// 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)
// Apple M1 Pro
// 16 GB

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the reconstruction depth to something smaller. I usually start with the default (8) which is generally very fast. Then I increase it slowly. Note that every step you increase the reconstruction depth the computation time increases exponentially, as does the memory (RAM) requirements. The crash is likely caused by alack of memory.